# How to name output file according to a command line argument in a bash script?

Tags: bash, terminal

These lines work when copy-pasted to the shell but don't work in a script:

```
ls -l file1 > /path/`echo !#:2`.txt
ls -l file2 > /path/`echo !#:2`.txt
```

```
ls -l file1 > /path/$(echo !#:2).txt
ls -l file2 > /path/$(echo !#:2).txt
```

What's the syntax for doing this in a bash script?

If possible, I would like to know how to do this for one file and for all files with the same extension in a folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-interactive shell has history expansion disabled.

Add the following two lines to your script to enable it:

```
set -o history
set -o histexpand
```

Answer (score 1):

(UPDATE: I misunderstood the original question as referring to arguments to the script, not arguments to the current command within the script; this is a rewritten answer.)

As @choroba said, history is disabled by default in scripts, because it's not really the right way to do things like this in a script.

The preferred way to do things like this in a script is to store the item in question (in this case the filename) in a variable, then refer to it multiple times in the command:

```
fname=file1
ls -l "$fname" > "/path/$fname.txt"
```

Note that you should almost always put variable references inside double-quotes (as I did above) to avoid trouble if they contain spaces or other shell metacharacters. If you want to do this for multiple files, use a `for` loop:

```
for fname in *; do   # this will repeat for each file (or directory) in the current directory
    ls -l "$fname" > "/path/$fname.txt"
done
```

If you want to operate on files someplace other than the current directory, things are a little more complicated. You can use `/inputpath/*`, but it'll include the path along with each filename (e.g. it'd run the loop with "/inputpath/file1", "/inputpath/file2", etc), and if you use that directly in the output redirect you'll get something like `> /path/inputpath/file1.txt` (i.e. the two different paths will get appended together), probably not what you want. In this case, you can use the `basename` command to strip off the unwanted path for output purposes:

```
for fpath in /inputpath/*; do
    ls -l "$fpath" > "/path/$(basename "$fpath").txt"
done
```

If you want a list of files with a particular extension, just use `*.foo` or `/inputpath/*.foo` as appropriate. However, in this case you'll wind up with the output going to files named e.g. "file1.foo.txt"; if you don't want stacked extensions, `basename` has an option to trim that as well:

```
for fpath in /inputpath/*.foo; do
    ls -l "$fpath" > "/path/$(basename "$fpath" .foo).txt"
done
```

Finally, it might be neater (depending how complex the actual operation is, and whether it occurs multiple times in the script) to wrap this in a function, then use that:

```
doStuffWithFile() {
    ls -l "$1" > "/path/$(basename "$1" "$2").txt"
}

for fpath in /inputpath/*.foo; do
    doStuffWithFile "$fpath" ".foo"
done
doStuffWithFile /otherpath/otherfile.bar .bar
```

Comment: Um, there's probably a misunderstanding or I have a completely botched version of Bash. When I do what you've said I have the output saved to `/path/.txt`. What I want is an individual output file for every line named after the command line argument, so if the argument is `foo` I want an output file named `foo.txt`. If the second argument is `file2` I want another output file named `file2.txt`. Obviously, it wouldn't make much sense doing this with `ls -l`, I only chose it to demonstrate my request because explaining what I actually need this for would be a bit complicated.